# Factory for ModelChoiceFields

Tags: python, django, customization, factory-pattern

I have two customers which use my django application `fooapp`.

- Customer1 wants ChoiceFields for Users to sorted by ('username', 'last_name', 'first_name')
- Customer2 wants ChoiceFields for Users to sorted by ('last_name', 'first_name')

I don't want to put customer specific code into `fooapp`.

How can I show all UserChoiceFields in the application in the way the customer likes it?

A simple solution would be a settings like `USER_CHOICE_ORDER_BY`. But sooner or later more difficult things would be needed. Then I could use a setting with an import-string to `USER_CHOICE_FIELD`.

Let's step back and do a birds eye look at this. Wouldn't it be nice to have **all** `ModelChoiceFields` be redirected to a field which was customized?

Example: A general solution should work for User, Group, ... all models (provided my django or provided from a third party).

Is there already something like this?

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong in using [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) ?

Comment: @DRC thank you for the feedback. I updated the question: I don't want to put customer specific code into fooapp.

How can I show all UserChoiceFields in the application in the way the customer likes it?

Comment: Your customers have their own Django code that uses your app as a part of it?

Comment: You should probably create a new widget based on the Select widget that looks for the setting.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DRC you should use the order_by Meta property in Models that will be affected. To make sure you don't have any customer specific code add this on your settings.py file like so:

```
MODEL_ORDER_BY = {
    'User':['username', 'last_name', 'first_name']
}
```

Then in your models.py file you can reference these values in this manner:

from django.conf import settings

```
Class User
    class Meta():
        # Making sure we have a settings value for this model first
        if self.__name__ in settings.MODEL_ORDER_BY:
            # Setting the list that's paired with this name
            order_by = settings.MODEL_ORDER_BY[self.__name__]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UserChoiceSortItem model to the fooapp and hold other models sort priority by objects of this model:

```
class UserChoiceSortItem(models.Model):
    _models = [
        (0, 'Profiles'),
        (1, 'Groups'),
        .
        .
        .
    ]
    sort_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    model = models.IntegerField(choices=_models)
    _model_type = None        

    @property
    def model_class(self):
      if self._model_type is None:
        from django.apps import apps
        _models = ['fooapp.CustomProfile', 'django.contrib.auth.Group', ...]
        self._model_type = apps.get_model(*_models[self.model].rsplit('.', 1))
      return self._model_type
```

and then you can use objects of UserChoiceSortItems model in view or forms:

```
.
.
.
order_fields = []
for sort_item in UserChoiceSortItems.objects.all().order_by('priority'):
    if isinstance(curent_model_objects, sort_items.model_class):
        order_fields.append(sort_item)
curent_model_objects.order_by(*order_fields)
choice_field.choices = order_fields
.
.
.
```

also you can initiate different state for different customers by using **fixtures** in fooapp(e.g. for first customer fooapp/fixtures/customer1.json):

```
[
    {
        'pk': 1,
        'model': 'fooapp.UserChoiceSortItems',
        'fields': {
            'sort_field': 'username',
            'priority': 0,
            'model': 'fooapp.CustomProfile'
        }
    },
    {
        'pk': 2,
        'model': 'fooapp.UserChoiceSortItems',
        'fields': {
            'sort_field': 'first_name',
            'priority': 1,
            'value': 'fooapp.CustomProfile'
        }
    },
    {
        'pk': 3,
        'model': 'fooapp.UserChoiceSortItems',
        'fields': {
            'sort_field': 'last_name',
            'priority': 2,
            'model': 'fooapp.CustomProfile'
        }
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

and for second customer fooapp/fixtures/customer2.json:

```
[
    {
        'pk': 1,
        'model': 'fooapp.UserChoiceSortItems',
        'fields': {
            'sort_field': 'first_name',
            'priority': 0,
            'model': 'fooapp.CustomProfile'
        }
    },
    {
        'pk': 2,
        'model': 'fooapp.UserChoiceSortItems',
        'fields': {
            'sort_field': 'last_name',
            'priority': 1,
            'value': 'fooapp.CustomProfile'
        }
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

and after `syncdb` you can load data by below command.

customer1:

```
./manage.py loaddata customer1
```

customer2:

```
./manage.py loaddata customer2
```

you and your customers can edit sort priorities on the django-admin and ENJOY...